# How to handle slashes on AD OUs and group names?

Tags: vbscript

I have a script to map printers based on AD groups. I found out it was not working for some users, and after some digging I realized it is related to slashes on group names or OUs.

My question is, how can I improve my script to handle this without having to change it entirelly?

Here is the part that handles user's identification and lists groups:

```
on error resume next

'determines the user who just logged on
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set WSHNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
'As soon as we tack on LDAP:// and construct an ADsPath we then bind to the user account in
'Active Directory and report back the groups the user belongs to; this can be done simply 
'by enumerating the values in the MemberOf attribute.


strUserPath = "LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject(strUserPath)


For Each objGroup in objUser.Groups
  strGroupName = objGroup.CN
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Regards

Comment: *... that it is related to slashes on group names or OUs* ... how? Do you get an error? What does it say? Is the code you posted the part that causes the problem? What do problematic values look like?

Comment: It should fail on both cases. I do get the following error: "(null): 0x80005000, referring to the line <Set objUser = GetObject(strUserPath)>

Comment: What does the value of `strUserPath` look like. Does it help if you escape slashes like this: `strUserPath = "LDAP://" & Replace(objSysInfo.UserName, "/", "\/")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping slashes in the username. They probably get misinterpreted in the LDAP URL.

```
strUserPath = "LDAP://" & Replace(objSysInfo.UserName, "/", "\/")
```